# How to insert record to database in Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, hsqldb

I am trying to deal with multitheading in Java.

I have read many articles and question(here on StackOverflow) but didn't find any clear examples how to use it.

I have Unique_Numbers table in HsqlDB database. There are 2 columns: NUMBER and QTY.
My task is to check if number exsists and increase QTY of number if yes and insert this number if not.

So, what did I get.

This is my configuration of Database

```
private final ComboPooledDataSource dataSource;

public Database(String url, String userName, String password) throws PropertyVetoException {
    dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUser(userName);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    dataSource.setMaxStatements(180);
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(5);
    dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(5);
}
```

This is my logic:

```
public void insertRow(String number) throws SQLException {
    int cnt = getCount(number);
    if (cnt == 0) {
        insert(number);
    } else if (cnt > 0) {
        update(number);
    }
}
```

Get count of number in the table

```
private int getCount(String number) {
        int cnt = 0;
        String sql = "select count(number) as cnt from \"PUBLIC\".UNIQUE_NUMBER where number='" + number + "'";
        try {
            Statement sta;
            try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
                sta = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = sta.executeQuery(sql);
                if (rs.next()) {
                    cnt = rs.getInt("cnt");
                }
            }
            sta.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("error select cnt by number" + e.toString());
        }

        return cnt;
    }
```

Insert and update

```
private boolean insert(String number) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "insert into \"PUBLIC\".UNIQUE_NUMBER (number, qty) values(?, ?)";
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ps.setString(1, number);
            ps.setInt(2, 0);
            ps.addBatch();
            ps.executeBatch();
            try {
                connection.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                connection.rollback();
                LOGGER.error(e.toString());
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean update(String number) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "update \"PUBLIC\".UNIQUE_NUMBER set (qty) = (?) where number = ?";
    int qty = selectQtyByNumber(number) + 1;
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            ps.setInt(1, qty);
            ps.setString(2, number);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            try {
                connection.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                connection.rollback();
                LOGGER.error(e.toString());
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

As I read, I must use Pool Connection. It is important to give one connection to each thread.
When I start my application, I got constraint exception or exception with Rollback: serialization failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my logs

```
[INFO] [generate38] ERROR se.homework.hwbs.tasks.un.server.threads.InsertRowThread - exception while inserting numberintegrity constraint violation: check constraint; SYS_CT_10114 table: UNIQUE_NUMBER

[INFO] [generate38] ERROR se.homework.hwbs.tasks.un.server.database.Database - error select cnt by number java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transaction rollback: serialization failure
[INFO] [generate38] ERROR se.homework.hwbs.tasks.un.server.threads.InsertRowThread - exception while inserting numbertransaction rollback: serialization failure

[INFO] [generate38] ERROR se.homework.hwbs.tasks.un.server.database.Database - error select cnt by number java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: transactionrollback: serialization failure
```

Comment: you are only getting into the rollback because you already have an exception - what is it?  I guess that you need to create/begin a transaction before commiting.

Comment: I just guess that if query has thrown an exception, then the transaction must rollback. I will try transaction and report here.

Comment: Your `getCount` method is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I added the part of my log file. Does it tell you something?

Comment: Thank you @TT. but now I only need to make it work.

Comment: You are getting a unique constraint violation i.e. The record that you are trying to insert already exists (or the primary key anyway)

Comment: Umm. I check count of number (primary key) in getCount method and only then I try to insert or update table. Doesn't it help me to prevent UniqueConstraintException? @ScaryWombat

Comment: when you do getCount you are quoting the number, maybe that is the reason

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have checked this queries in DB. It must work correct.

Comment: You should try as hard as you can to execute the entire transaction in a single statement.

Comment: @EJP when I try to execute this code not from thread, it works correct. One by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**the non-transactional way**

Do the increment first

```
update UNIQUE_NUMBER set qty = qty + 1 where number = ?
```

Check if it did update any row, insert the number if it didn't

```
int rowsMatched = ps.executeUpdate();
if(rowsMatched == 0) {
    try {
        insert into UNIQUE_NUMBER (number, qty) values(?, 0)
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // the insert will fail if another thread has already
        // inserted the same number. check if that's the case
        // and if so, increment instead.
        if(isCauseUniqueConstraint(e)) {
            update UNIQUE_NUMBER set qty = qty + 1 where number = ?
        } else {throw e;}
    }
}
```

No transaction handling (`setAutoCommit(false)`, `commit()` or `rollback()`) reqired.

**the transactional way**

If you still want to do this in a transactional way, you need to do all steps within a single transaction, like @EJP suggested:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
// check if number exists
// increment if it does
// insert if it doesn't
// commit, rollback & repeat in case of error
connection.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Set auto commit back to true if this code shares the connection pool with other code (as that's the default state others will expect the connection to be in) or make it clear that connections in the pool will always be in transactional mode.

In your code, `getCount` will sometimes get a connection in auto commit mode (first use) and sometimes get a connection in transactional mode (reused after `insert` and/or `update`) - that's why you see rollback exceptions in `getCount`.